# Laravel-redirects even authenticated users to login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

### **Before minus this question, or report a duplicate, please read it completely.**

I use a default Laravel Autentification. But for some reason, it's somehow broke down.
When I try to login or register, if auth is success it redirects try to redirects me to a correct link, but but at the same time returns me to /login.

### Example with dump

[image]

**Debugbar after trying auth**
[image]

### Source files

**1. My routes:**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/confirm', function () {
    return view('confirm');
})->name('confirm');
Route::post('/confirm', 'EmployeeController@store')->name('addworker');
Route::get('users/{id}', 'EmployeeController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+')->name('account');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**2. Changes into login and register controllers:**

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return route('account',['id'=> auth()->user()->id]);
}
```

**3.Methods in a EmployeeController, that action in auth:**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('confirmated');
}

public function show($id)
{
    return view('account');
}
```

4. My middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Employee;

class CheckConfirm
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $id = Auth::id();

            $empl = Employee::where('user_id', '=', $id)->first();
            Debugbar::info($empl);
            if ($empl == null) {
                return redirect()->route('confirm');
            } else {
                dump($empl);

                return $next($request);
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

### What *did not* help me

1. clearing the cache and browser history including the artisan commands: `cache:clear` and `config:clean`
2. Disable my middleware or auth midlleware in controllers constructor
3. Disable all middleware in contructor led to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQKzI.png)
4. Solutions in question duplicates, or in other forums

If there is not enough information in the question, you can download my entire project on GitHub: https://github.com/Vladislav2018/last.chance/

Comment: Have you got the sessions driver set to file? If so, please open the folder `storage/framework/sessions`, try to log in a few times and then see if there is a new file for each time you have tried to log in.

Comment: @RossWilson Yeah, each time I try to login, new files appear in this directory, their content is the same as in the debugbar, for example: `a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"0DhzeXUZ4InmLU7tQ7GaSUqxjwgE1AhE3WvURR8b";s:3:"url";a:0:{}s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:24:"http://last.chance/login";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:50:"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d";i:6;}`